# Getting the original row of a numpy 2d slice in np.nonzero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

in my program I take a 2d slice of a N*N matrix:

```
message = np.eye(10)
depth = 4
slice = message [depth:]
```

output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]

my_ones = np.nonzero(slice)
```

output:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

So, as we can see, it considers the slice to be a new array, and so the rows for the nonzero function start at 0, instead of at 4.  But I want the row numbers relative to the original array, rather than just the portion I chose to examine.

I could, of course, save the number of removed rows (or columns, if that is the case), and then for each row of the nonzero function I would add that number.  But, that is horribly inelegant and will make my code gross if I am making lots of varying slices.

Is there a way to do this where the nonzero function would realize that it's looking at a slice of a larger array and output the row relative to that context?

> For example, in this case, I would want the desired output of:
>   `(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))`, because those were the actual rows in the original 2d array (message).

Thank you.

Comment: sure, edit made.

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Because ```depth[4:]``` makes no sense to me as ```depth``` is an integer (```depth = 4```)...

Comment: You are correct, that was a stupid mistake.  It's as simple as you think it is.

Comment: `slice` **is** a new array.  It is a `view`, and shares the data buffer with `message`.  In theory it would be possible to identifying slicing values from some underlying parameters, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Instead you should just keep track of the original indexing yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather copy `message` into `slice`and replace its `depth` first rows by zeros and then use `np.nonzero` following

```
slice = np.array(message)
slice[:depth] = 0
my_ones = np.nonzero(slice)
```

Output:

```
(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html):

```
import numpy as np

message = np.eye(10)
depth = 4

message_masked = np.ma.masked_array(message, np.zeros_like(message, dtype=bool), copy=False)
message_masked.mask[:4] = True

print(np.ma.nonzero(message_masked))
```

Output:

```
(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Kefeng91's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427422/1887559) is correct, but a bit ineffective. Numpy will crunch a lot of numbers, to get something very simple :)

It is obvious that, when you tranced your array, you knew for sure how many raws you had removed from the top, right? Just add this number back to the raw number, like this `my_ones[0] += depth` - that is all...